# Server-Sent Event (SSE) - The client always receives the previous event data instead of the current one

Tags: spring

In my Spring Boot application, I implemented SSE Event using SseEmitter for multiple client connections. However, the client always receives the previous Server-Sent Event (SSE) data instead of the current one. How can I resolve this problem?

See the below code :

@RestController
public class SseEventController {

```
private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<SseEmitter> emitters = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

@GetMapping(value = "/latest-stock-price/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public SseEmitter subscribeToEvents(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setHeader("X-Accel-Buffering", "no");
    try {
    
        // Create SseEmitter with no timeout
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);

        // Add the emitter to the list
        this.emitters.add(emitter);

        emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitters.remove(emitter)); 

            return emitter;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(Constants.EXCEPTION + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostMapping("/latest-stock-price/update")
@EventListener
public AlphaResponse<Boolean> receiveData(@RequestBody List<LtpStockRequest> lptUpdate) throws BadRequestException {
    AlphaResponse<Boolean> aphaResponse = new AlphaResponse<>();
    AlphaResult<Boolean> alphaResult = new AlphaResult<>();
    try {
        ServerEventValidator.validateLtpStockRequest(lptUpdate);
        log.info("Stock Price Update Here.." + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(lptUpdate));
        // Process the data received from the external API.
        // Send the processed data to connected SSE clients.

        this.sendDataToEmitters(lptUpdate).exceptionally(ex -> {
            log.error(Constants.EXCEPTION + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(ex.getMessage());
        });

        alphaResult.setResult(true);
        aphaResponse.setAlphaResult(alphaResult);
        aphaResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        aphaResponse.setStatusMessage(Constants.RECORD_UPDATED);

        return aphaResponse;

    } catch (BadRequestException e) {
        log.error(Constants.EXCEPTION + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(Constants.EXCEPTION + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Void> sendDataToEmitters(List<LtpStockRequest> lptUpdate) {
    List<SseEmitter> deadEmitters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SseEmitter emitter : this.emitters) {
        try {
            emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("latest-stock-price").data(lptUpdate));
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            emitter.completeWithError(e);
            deadEmitters.add(emitter);
        }
    }
    this.emitters.removeAll(deadEmitters);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

}

I am implementing Server-Sent Events (SSE) and sending the data using another API. However, when I tried to push the data to the client from the '/stock-price/update' API, the client did not receive the first posted data. Instead, the client received the previous posted data when the data was posted for the second time using the same API.
In other words, the client always received the previous posted data instead of the current one.